# Loading Images on Jpgraph... until I reload

Tags: php, phpexcel, jpgraph

this is my first request in this web.

I have a problem with jpgraph. Some times, the images aren't produce in this script with phpexcel. Until I reload the page, the images produces

```
enter code here $hrActual =date("H-i-s");
$fechasActual = date("d-m-Y");

$graph = new PieGraph(500,400);
$graph->SetShadow();

$graph->title->Set("ELISAS");
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

$p1 = new PiePlot3D($Datos);
$graph->Add($p1);
$p1->ExplodeSlice(1);
$p1->SetCenter(0.50);
$p1->SetLegends($Leyendas);
$p1->SetSliceColors(array('#00AF50','#FFC000'));
$graph->legend->Pos(0.4,0.95,"center","bottom"); 

$graph->Stroke('../graficas/img/Grafica_Efectividad_Elisas_'.$hrActual.'_'.  $fechasActual.'.png');
enter code here// Agrega una imagen
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('image name');
$objDrawing->setDescription('PHPExcel logo');
$objDrawing->setPath('../graficas/img/Grafica_Efectividad_Elisas_'.$hrActual.'_'.$fechasActual.'.png');
//$objDrawing->setHeight(100);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A'.$i);
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(10);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

I'll apreciate if you can't help me.

Thanks